# How to iterate over a list of list of lists of lists of lists... of list of pair of coordinates in python?

Tags: python, list, recursion, data-structures

I am trying to iterate over a list of lists of lists... of list of pair of coordinates in python and I want to sum a value to each of these pair of coordinates but I also want to keep the structure.

I think an example is worth more than a thousand words so:

```
coordinates = [[[-15.418887, 28.180395], [-15.418887, 28.180395]],
 [[-15.794088, 28.018681], [-15.794088, 28.018681]]]
```

This is a very basic example but is not the real case. In the real each of the list has variables lengths except for the pair of coordinates. So maybe there are 4 lists until the list of list of pair coordinates or it could be 3, it is variable

I want to add 3 (for example) to each of these coordinates but keeping the original structure ( I don't want to flat the list of lists of list ....)

#### Maybe this is useful for trying to answer the question:

- I have a geojson file and I want to move a feature ( a region) to another place. To do this I am trying to sum a constant value to latitude and longitude to each coordinate of the region
- I think this could be done using recursion but I am not sure how

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it guaranteed to have two nested lists in one list?

Comment: @Harsh no, it could be variable, could be three, four or more nested lists. It is variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Comment: You can convert the list to a numpy list and then simply do the operation you want on the list like `cd = np.array(coordinates)` and `cd = cd + 3`

Comment: @Renat as I said, I want to keep the original structure I don't want to flatten the list of lists.... So it is not useful, thanks anyway.

Comment: So you basically have an n-ary tree that you want to walk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to handle the general case. Just check if you have a list and recurse, otherwise return the result of the addition:

```
def add_to_list(l, n):
    if not isinstance(l, list):
        return l + n
    return [add_to_list(sub, n) for sub in l]
   
coordinates = [[[-15.418887, 28.180395], [-15.418887, 28.180395]],[[-15.794088, 28.018681], [-15.794088, 28.018681]]]

add_to_list(coordinates, 3)    
#[[[-12.418887, 31.180395], [-12.418887, 31.180395]], [[-12.794088, 31.018681], [[-12.794088, 31.018681]]]]

# A more general case:
add_to_list([1, [2, [5, [6]]], 3], 2)
# [3, [4, [7, [8]]], 5]

# Degenerate cases
add_to_list([], 2)
# []
add_to_list(5, 2) 
# 7
```

This assumes that your nested data will *either* be numbers or lists.

Answer (score 1):

```py
coordinates = [[[-15.418887, 28.180395], [-15.418887, 28.180395]],
               [[-15.794088, 28.018681], [-15.794088, 28.018681]]]

def recursively_add3(l):
    if isinstance(l, float):
        return l
    
    for index, inner_list in enumerate(l):
        inner_result = recursively_add3(inner_list)
        if inner_result is not None:
            l[index] = inner_result + 3
    
    return None

recursively_add3(coordinates)
```

which gives the result

```
[[[-12.418887, 31.180395], [-12.418887, 31.180395]]
, [[-12.794088, 31.018681], [-12.794088, 31.018681]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

General `map` approach to apply a function only to the innermost elements of a randomly deeply nested list:

```
def map_nested(fnc, lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return fnc(lst)
    return [map_nested(fnc, x) for x in lst]
    # or for in-place mutation:
    # lst[:] = (map_nested(fnc, x) for x in lst)
    # return lst

add3 = lambda x: x+3

map_nested(add3, coordinates)
# [[[-12.418887, 31.180395], [-12.418887, 31.180395]], 
#  [[-12.794088, 31.018681], [-12.794088, 31.018681]]]
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than recursive methods implemented by @SiArce or @`Mark Meyer`?

Comment: Efficiency is the same. It is just more reusable as it provides a way to apply any function (not just one that adds 3 or n) at an arbitrary nesting level. I find it more readable, too, as the `map_nested` focuses solely on its traversal task.

Comment: @Ángel, Another difference is that my result is in place, the other 2 return a new list

Comment: MarkMeyer's and mine, do create and return a new list object, while SiAce mutates the existing one.

Comment: @SiAce Yup, was just pointing that out and added an in-place alternative to my approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 3D vector (lists of lists of lists) of coordinates right? Then your loop should be triple to access to all the variables on that 3D vector.

```
for x in list: #x is a list of lists
  for y in x: #y is a list
    for z in y: #z is a pair of coordinates
      #Your code here
```

Comment: As I said, In my case the length of the list is variable so it is not guaranteed to be 3D vector, however thank you very much for your response.

Comment: In that case, you can use this:

for x in range(0, lengh(list)):
  list[x] is the way to access your elements

That still allows to triple loop because if your list is empty, it will just ignore the loop